Unable to set aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration with prefix and object_size_greater_than filters
Unable to set delete lifecycle configuration policy on S3 bucket using terraform with two filters:

object_size_greater_than = 0
prefix = "demo/"

I am using terraform version v1.1.2 and AWS provider version 5.6.2
I have written below terraform code:
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "lifecycle_test_bucket" {
  bucket = "lifecycle-test-bucket3210912"
}
resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "lifecycle_test_bucket" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.lifecycle_test_bucket.id

  rule {
    id = "rule-1"

    filter {
      and {
        object_size_greater_than = 0
        prefix                   = "demo/"
        # object_size_less_than    = 1
      }
    }

    # ... other transition/expiration actions ...

    status = "Enabled"
    expiration {
      days = 1
    }
  }
}


Getting below error while doing terraform apply:

aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration.lifecycle_test_bucket:
Modifying... [id=lifecycle-test-bucket3210912] ╷ │ Error: updating S3
Bucket Lifecycle Configuration (lifecycle-test-bucket3210912):
MalformedXML: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not
validate against our published schema │ status code: 400, request id:
6WHRQNV7F8TZSYVH, host id:
AKwJJoPAsonTTVoPc49N3V/hLT8qn3zn150VgsV0rWi48a9ldogrf/Suz/tqblir9raYA/QCW9U=
│ │ with aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration.lifecycle_test_bucket,
│ on main.tf line 412, in resource
"aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "lifecycle_test_bucket": │
412: resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration"
"lifecycle_test_bucket" {


Please help me here
